# Is there a general result for $\sum\prod_{i\neq j}k_j\mod k$ with $\prod k_i=k$ with pairwise coprime $k_i,k_j,i\neq j$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $\prod_{i\in \{1,2,3...r\}}k_i=k$ with pairwise coprime $k_i,k_j,i\neq j$, so $ (k_i,k_j)=1$. What is

$$\sum_{i\in \{1,2,3...r\}} \prod_{i\neq j} k_j\equiv x\mod k?$$

Is there a simplified expression for $x$? I tried to find a simplified result through the Chinese remainder theorem, but without success.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sum_{i\in \{1,2,3...r\}}\prod_{i\neq j} k_{\color{red}j}$?

Comment: $k_i$ can not ne smalled tham the (i-1)th prime.